# What is the equivalent of PHP's $_POST in a Perl CGI script and how can I use it?

Tags: php, perl

I have two Perl files: `action.pl` and the other is `test.pl`

`action.pl` has a form:

```
print $cgi->header, <<html;
<form action="test.pl" method="post">
html
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow)
{
print $cgi->header, <<html;
ID:<input name="pid" value="@row[0]" readonly="true"/><br/>
Name: <input name="pname" value="@row[1]"/><br/>
Description : <input name="pdescription" value="@row[2]"/><br/>
Unit Price :<input name="punitprice" value="@row[3]"/><br/>
html
}
print $cgi->header, <<html
<input type="submit" value="update Row">
</form>
html
```

What should I write in `test.pl` so as to access the form values submitted by the user?

In other words, what equivalent of PHP's `$_POST['pid']` in Perl?

Comment: Do you realize that your `test.pl` will receive all product ids, all product names etc regardless of which fields changed, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CGI and `param()`

```
  use CGI ':standard';
  my $id    = param('id');
```

Comment: Note that, given the form, `param('pid')` will return a reference to an array containing all product ids on the page.

Answer (score 5):

```
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new();

for my $p ($cgi->param) {       # loop through all form inputs
    my $val = $cgi->param($p);  # get param's value
    # ...
}
```

To get the value of the 'pid' input, use:

```
$cgi->param('pid');
```

Update:
The test script may look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new();

printf "%sPid:%s", $cgi->header, $cgi->param('pid');
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more ..like what exactly would come in test.pl    i am having trouble implementing your code

Comment: @dexter: See the updated answer. Make sure your script has correct permissions.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should turn on [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html). Had you done so, you would have noticed that you should use `$row[1]`, `$row[2]` ... to access individual elements of `@row`. `@row[0]` creates a single element array slice.

Second, you would benefit from separating logic from presentation by using a templating module such as [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Template). Having `while` loops mixed in with heredocs make for unreadable code.

You can access the parameter values passed to your script by using a CGI form processing package. These days, I prefer to use [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Simple) rather than [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) because `CGI::Simple` has saner defaults and does not have the HTML generation baggage that comes with `CGI.pm`.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI::Simple;

my $cgi = CGI::Simple->new;
my $pname = $cgi->param('pname');
```

Finally, keep in mind that you still need to validate 'pid' even though it is specified as `readonly` in the form. I would also recommend using [CGI::Application](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Application) to provide handlers for various actions rather than having a different script for each one.

Here is a simple example:

```
#!perl

use strict; use warnings;
use CGI::Simple;
use HTML::Template;

my $cgi = CGI::Simple->new;

# For demo purposes only. I would use CGI::Application
$cgi->param ? process_form($cgi) : show_form($cgi);

sub process_form {
    my ($cgi) = @_;

    print $cgi->header('text/plain'),
        sprintf("%s : %s\n",
            $cgi->param('pid'),
            $cgi->param('pname'),
        )
    ;
    return;
}

sub show_form {
    my ($cgi) = @_;
    my $tmpl = HTML::Template->new(scalarref => template() );
    $tmpl->param(
        PRODUCTS => [
            { PID => '1234', PNAME => 'Widget' },
            { PID => '4321', PNAME => 'Wombat' },
        ]
    );
    print $cgi->header, $tmpl->output;
    return;
}

sub template {
    return \ <<EO_TMPL;
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<TMPL_LOOP PRODUCTS>
<form method="POST">
<p><input name="pid" readonly="1" value="<TMPL_VAR PID>">
<input name="pname" value="<TMPL_VAR PNAME>"><input
type="submit" value="Update"></p></form>
</TMPL_LOOP>
</body>
</html>
EO_TMPL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From CGI.pm as an alternative.

```
FETCHING THE PARAMETER LIST AS A HASH:
           use CGI;
           my $params = $q->Vars;
           print $params->{'address'};

           my @foo = split("\0",$params->{'foo'});
           my %params = $q->Vars;
```